# javascript how to use a variable to reference an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object like this

```
var obj={
    a:{x: "someValue", y:"anotherValue"},
    b:{x: "bValue", y:"anotherbValue"}
};
```

and I am trying to reference it like this

```
function(some_value){
    alert("some_value is " + some_value + " with type " + typeof some_value);
    // prints  some_value is a  with type  string 
    var t;
    t=obj[some_value]["x"];   // doesn't work   
    some_value="a";
    t=obj[some_value]["x"];  // this does work
    t=obj["a"]["x"];     // and so does this
}
```

I would really like understand what is going on here . Ideally I'd like to reference my
object with the value passed to the function. 
Thanks

Comment: sorry there is a typo - there is not two double quotes on the last object in the real code

Comment: You can edit your question. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10369028/edit

Comment: If `some_value` is indeed `"a"`, then `t=obj[some_value]["x"];` will work.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that your variable `some_value` must not contain the value `a`. It is possible that it has extra white space characters.

Comment: +1 Seems like it may be a whitespace issue judging by the output of the `alert`.

Comment: yes that was it- thanks, at least I won't forget to check for that again since I have been fiddling with it for ages.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, when a property does not exist, it returns an `undefined`. in the case of the following code, if the value contained in the variable `some_value` does not exist as a property in `obj`, `t` is undefined

```
//if some_value is neither a nor b
t = obj[some_value] // t === undefined
```

if you try to extract a property from an `undefined` value, the browser reports an error:

```
//if some_value is neither a nor b
t = obj[some_value]["x"] // error
```

you can check the existence of a property before you try accessing it by using `hasOwnProperty()`.

```
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(somevalue)){
    //exists
} else {
    //does not exist
}
```

you can do a "loose check" but it's not reliable as anything "falsy" will call it "non-existent" even though there is a value.

```
if(obj[somevalue]){
    //is truthy
} else {
    //obj[somevalue] either:
    //does not exist
    //an empty string
    //a boolean false
    //null
    //anything "falsy"
}
```

Comment: thanks, I used your suggestion hasOwnProperty and found that it was returning false,  some_value="my_lookup_value " Whitespace! Ahggg